# Integral of non-Gaussian distribution, random walk?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I would like to evaluate

$$
F = \frac{\mathbb{E} \left\{\left(\int_0^T x^3(t) dt \right)^2\right\}}{\mathbb{E} \left\{\left(\int_0^T x(t) dt \right)^2 \right\} }
\approx \frac{\mathbb{E} \left\{\left(\frac{T}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^3 \right)^2\right\}}{\mathbb{E} \left\{\left(\frac{T}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n \right)^2 \right\} }
$$

(The second term with the sum is an acceptable approximation if the continuous way causes problems)

If $x(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and independent for each $t$, the denominator is a **random walk** and the output variance is proportional to the integration length $T$, i.e., the denominator would be something like $\sim \sigma^2 T$.

However, $x^3(t)$ is not Gaussian so I cannot evaluate the numerator. Any clues?

Generally, I would like to extend the evaluation to cases where $x(t)$ is not independent for each $t$ (i.e., colored noise or bandlimited white Gaussian noise).

**The context is as follows:** I have a nonlinear amplifier (for simplicity only $y(t)= a_0 x(t) + a_3 x^3(t)$ followed by an ideal integrator. I would like to calculate the expected mean squared error after $T$ seconds if the input signal follows certain statistics, in the simplest case it is white Gaussian.

The normalized mean squared error in dB can be obtained as

$$
\mathrm{NMSE} = 20\log(4/3) - 2 \, \mathrm{IIP_3} + 20 + F
$$

Let me also add that in the absence of the integral, simply $F = \frac{\mathbb{E} \left\{\left(x^3(t)\right)^2\right\}}{\mathbb{E} \left\{\left(x(t)\right)^2 \right\} } = 15 \sigma^4$, although the The Cube of a Normal Distribution is Indeterminate.

Comment: Your $x$ is white noise? Then your numerator is not defined, since white noise does not exist in the pathwise sense. You should consider a concrete case where this cubing operation is defined.

Comment: I do not understad - maybe this is because it is continuous. We can use a discrete-time case if it makes things easier. E.g. take $N=100$ iid Gaussian numbers and define the sequence $x_n$. Then $\Sigma_n x_n$ is a random walk as written above and $\Sigma_n x_n^3$ is defined as well.

Comment: No, you cannot compute this. Not only because both integrals are not defined (although $x$ *with finite variance* is defined, contrary to what @Ian wrote, it is not measurable as a function of $t$). But also evaluating the expectation of a ratio of things, which are not independent, is usually hopeless. Just try to evaluate $E[(X_1^3+X_2^3+X_3^3)/(X_1+X_2+X_3)]$ with $X_1,X_2,X_3$ iid Gaussian. Why do you need to evaluate it at all? Could you provide the context?

Comment: So the integral of a cube of white Gaussian is not analytically computable? (Clearly I can obtain the result numerically in MATLAB). Regarding the ratios of dependent variables I disagree: Without the integration I have $\frac{\mathbb{E}\left\{x^3\right\}^2}{\mathbb{E}\left\{x\right\}^2}$ which evaluates to $15 \sigma^4$ and matches my simulation results perfectly. This is easy and not hopeless. I added the context to my question. Maybe there's another way around that?

Comment: Actually I just realized a significant mistake: $E(a/b)\neq E(a)/E(b)$. I corrected the posting. Maybe this changes things a bit? EDIT: Even more was wrong. It's not the expected value but the square :-(

Comment: You still need to precisely formulate what process you are looking at. I misunderstood you (I thought you were talking about "ideal white noise" which has infinite variance. Nevertheless, processes consisting of iid normals with finite variance at each of continuum-many times "basically don't exist" (their paths are not measurable functions of $t$). Perhaps you would like to look at $\frac{E \left [ \left ( \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^3 \frac{T}{N} \right )^2 \right ]}{E \left [ \left ( \sum_{n=1}^N x_n \frac{T}{N} \right )^2 \right ]}$ where $x_n$ are iid normals?

Comment: Yes, that would work too if it simplifies things. (it would be even better if a weighting factor in the sum would be included (but not too important). But any idea to deal with the sum? (Updated question)

Comment: Just a remark how I solved the problem: The sum squared can just be expanded into a sum of $N^2$ terms and then operate the expectation operation for each term (because it is linear).